# Angular Minification - Causes app to halt

Tags: angularjs

I have the following provider that is causing the application to not do anything, yet no errors on the console... I have looked at it for hours to no avail.

```
(function (angular) {
"use strict";

angular.module('app').provider('templateRepository', function () {
    var templateKey = 'template:',
        useCache = true,
        cacheDuration = 30,
        autoCleanCache = true,
        cleanCacheInterval = 30;

    return {
        $get: ['$http', '$q', '$interval', function ($http, $q, $interval) {
            var getFromCache = function (key) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            },
            getFromServer = function (name) {
                return $http.get('Template/Index?name=' + name).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            isExpired = function (item) {
                return ((parseInt(new Date() - new Date(item.timestamp)) / (1000 * 60)) >= cacheDuration);
            },
            removeFromCache = function (key) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
            },
            saveToCache = function (key, value) {
                localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({
                    timestamp: new Date().toUTCString(),
                    value: value
                }));
            },
            cleanCache = function () {
                for (var key in localStorage) {
                    if (key.substring(0, 9) === templateKey) {
                        if (isExpired(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)))) {
                            removeFromCache(key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            if (useCache && autoCleanCache) {
                $interval(function () {
                    cleanCache();
                }, (cleanCacheInterval * 60 * 1000));
            }

            return {
                get: function (name) {
                    var key = templateKey + name,
                        d = $q.defer(),
                        item;

                    if (useCache) {
                        item = getFromCache(key);

                        if (item === null) {
                            getFromServer(name).then(function (template) {
                                saveToCache(key, template);
                                d.resolve(template);
                            });
                        } else {
                            if (isExpired(item)) {
                                getFromServer(name).then(function (template) {
                                    saveToCache(key, template);
                                    d.resolve(template);
                                });
                            } else {
                                d.resolve(item.value);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        getFromServer(name).then(function (template) {
                            d.resolve(template);
                        });
                    }

                    return d.promise;
                }
            };
        }],
        configureCache: function (enable, duration, autoClean, cleanInterval) {
            useCache = enable;
            cacheDuration = duration;
            autoCleanCache = autoClean;
            cleanCacheInterval = cleanInterval;
        }
    };
});

}(this.angular));
```

Comment: This might not be related but why `this.angular` and not just `angular` as the variable being passed into the closure?

Comment: @dcodesmith Makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used http://jscompress.com/ to minify and the rest of my application worked fine. I didn't test your code in anyway. Perhaps try the below minified code or share your minified js.

```
(function(e){"use strict";e.module("app").provider("templateRepository",function(){var e="template:",t=true,n=30,r=true,i=30;return{$get:["$http","$q","$interval",function(s,o,u){var a=function(e){return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(e))},f=function(e){return s.get("Template/Index?name="+e).then(function(e){return e.data})},l=function(e){return parseInt(new Date-new Date(e.timestamp))/(1e3*60)>=n},c=function(e){localStorage.removeItem(e)},h=function(e,t){localStorage.setItem(e,JSON.stringify({timestamp:(new Date).toUTCString(),value:t}))},p=function(){for(var t in localStorage){if(t.substring(0,9)===e){if(l(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(t)))){c(t)}}}};if(t&&r){u(function(){p()},i*60*1e3)}return{get:function(n){var r=e+n,i=o.defer(),s;if(t){s=a(r);if(s===null){f(n).then(function(e){h(r,e);i.resolve(e)})}else{if(l(s)){f(n).then(function(e){h(r,e);i.resolve(e)})}else{i.resolve(s.value)}}}else{f(n).then(function(e){i.resolve(e)})}return i.promise}}}],configureCache:function(e,s,o,u){t=e;n=s;r=o;i=u}}})})(this.angular)
```